# Abstractive text summarization using seq2seq model

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to do abstractive text summarization using seq2seq model. I want to know the working principle of seq2seq model for summarization along with attention mechanism.

Comment: can you be more specified please tell us what you did and where are you stuck ?

Comment: thanks for your response.  to be frank i do not understand the working of seq2seqmodel.  i want to know how the model process the text and produces a summary.  i would be really helpful if you provide some insights regarding seq2seq model for summarization.  i haven't started it yet

Answer (score 1):

this is a [blog series](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods#blogs) that talks in much detail from the very beginning of how seq2seq works till reaching the newest research approaches

Also this [repo](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods) collects multiple implementations on building a text summarization model, it runs these models on google colab, and hosts the data on google drive, so no matter how powerful your computer is, you can use google colab which is a free system to train your deep models on

If you like to see the text summarization in action, you can use this [free api](https://eazymind.herokuapp.com/arabic_sum).

I truly hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much.  it means a lot.  thanks for the timely help